# Ubuntu 16.04: Erroneously executed `mv` with `~/*` as target and can't understand the outcome

Tags: ubuntu, mv

While wanting to upgrade MongoDB from 3.4 to 3.6 I went into the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. From there I wanted to move the `mongodb-org-3.4.list` and `mongodb-org-3.4.list.save` files to my home directory.

I first executed a `mv mongodb-org-3.4 ~/*`. For some reason I managed to move the wildcard to the end of the command. After seeing the notification `mv: cannot stat 'mongodb-org-3.4': No such file or directory`, I then "corrected" this by typing `mv mongodb-org-3.4* ~/*`, again with the wildcard at the end. I did not use sudo, I was not root.

As a response for `mv mongodb-org-3.4* ~/*` I got

```
mv: cannot remove 'mongodb-org-3.4.list': Permission denied
mv: cannot remove 'mongodb-org-3.4.list.save': Permission denied
mv: inter-device move failed: '/home/user/atlassian' to '/home/user/windows-storage/atlassian'; unable to remove target: Directory not empty
mv: inter-device move failed: '/home/user/data' to '/home/user/windows-storage/data'; unable to remove target: Directory not empty
mv: cannot create symbolic link '/home/user/windows-storage/dockervolumes/sharemanager': Read-only file system
```

I then went into the `/home/user/windows-storage` directory and ls'd it, only to find that probably all of my home directory got copied (???) to this mounted directory.

Have I damaged something? Or have I "only" copied the home directory to this mounted directory?

Why did this `mv` command somehow behave like `cp`?

Ok, turns out files were moved, but not all, since I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> because <sup>it was taking an unusually long time to finish</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asterisks were expanded by your shell, so the resulting command was

```
mv mongodb-org-3.4.list mongodb-org-3.4.list.save ... ~/atlassian ~/... ~/data ... ~/windows-storage
```

(based on the errors you posted). Thus you instructed `mv` to move all the listed files and directories into `~/windows-storage` — your home directory’s contents haven’t been copied, they’ve been moved.

To recover, you’ll need to look at all the contents of `~/windows-storage`, and move whatever is appropriate back (taking care with `*`).

Comment: Now I'm a bit scared.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always have `set -x` in my interactive shell sessions... :-)

Comment: @Daniel I don’t think you’ll have lost any of the data that was in your home directory, but you might well have overwritten data in `~/windows-storage`. Whatever you do, don’t panic.

Comment: Ok, i've lost file metadata since they got moved onto an ntfs volume, also the timestamps changed. On 100mb rrd (rrdtool) got lost, because during the `mv` I `ctrl+\ `'d which probalbly was during the move of that file so it only got moved halfway, and when moving all back that truncated file probably overwrote the original one. At least I hope that this is the only problem. I had to chmod -R three dirs, which I hope won't cause any problems, since some were docker volumes mounted inside containers. Reminds me of my `rm -rf ~` while trying to recursively delete a directory named `~`...